# How to replace page links for hashtag slug in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a single page site within WordPress, that contains multiple sections. These sections are pages in WordPress. Than I loop with a custom loop through all pages and display them inside my `index.php` file:

```
<?php 
    $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
    $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
?>
<?php if ($loop) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <?php $slides = get_field('flexslider'); ?>
    <?php 
        if ($slides) { 
            get_template_part( 'templates/slideshow' );
        } else {
            get_template_part( 'templates/parallax' );
        } 
    ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**MENU**

There are two things where I am stuck at. The first one, is that I make use of `wp_nav_menu` to generate a menu on the page. This is working correct, but because I make use of one single page, that contains all the pages in it, I don't need to link each page with the external links to each page. I would like to replace it with hashtag (#)slug, so it will be navigate to the right section on the page. The slug should be the same as the slug of the created page.

At the moment my menu looks like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
            'menu' => 'primary-menu',
            'container' => 'nav',
            'container_id' => 'primary-navwrapper',
            'menu_id' => 'listnav'
));
?>
```

Beside this, I would like to use the menu order that can be ranking inside "appearance > menu" to position the sections (pages) on the right place. To do this I make use of the `menu_order` inside the loop that walk through all pages, so above method should work for this solution, because I want to give the clients the possibility to easily position the section on the page by simple drag and drop the menu in the right place, with one handling.

Comment: look up wp nav walker, you can modify the output from there, there are a few filters in there as well.

Comment: Do you have an basic example or an source for me? It would be nice.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class